# Script to unpack archives of various kinds

Tags: beginner, bash

Just looking for some feedback and constructive criticism. This is the second script I ever made. Just recently started learning the basics. Anyway just wanted to post the script and see if maybe I can get some input on where I can maybe do things better.

The script is for extracting the compressed file types you run into the most on Linux. I added the option to extract to a directory of the user's choosing and not just keep it limited to only the working directory.

I feel like I have too many `if`/`then` statements and they can somehow be better but I'm not sure. And not sure if I Implemented the exits the right way. Some of you are probably gonna cringe when you see this lol! Anyway if you can help thanks.

````
#!/bin/bash

error() {
    echo "For help, type: nzip -h"
}

usage() {
    echo "Usage: nzip [FILE]..."
    echo "By default file(s) will be extracted to the working directory."
    echo
    echo "OPTIONS.."
    echo
    echo "-d, --directory, eg. nzip [file] [-d] [directory]"
    echo
    echo
}

if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
    error >&2
    exit 1
fi

if [ $# -eq 1 ]
then
    case $1 in
        -h) usage
            exit 0
            ;;
        *.7z) 7z e "$1"
            ;;
        *.tar.bz2) tar xjvf "$1"
            ;;
        *.tar.gz) tar xzvf "$1"
            ;;
        *.rar) unrar e "$1"
            ;;
        *.tar) tar xvf "$1"
            ;;
        *.bz2) bunzip2 "$1"
            ;;
        *.tbz) tar xjvf "$1"
            ;;
        *.gz) gunzip "$1"
            ;;
        *.tgz) tar xzvf "$1"
            ;;
        *.jar) unzip "$1"
            ;;
        *.xz) tar xvf "$1"
            ;;
        *.zip) unzip "$1"
            ;;
        *.Z) uncompress "$1"
            ;;
        *) echo "No extraction option for $1" >&2
            exit 1
    esac
    exit 0
fi

if [ $# -eq 3 ] && [ "$2" = "-d" ]
then
    case $1 in
        *.7z) 7z e "$1" -o"$3"
            ;;
        *.tar.bz2) tar xjvf "$1" -C "$3"
            ;;
        *.tar.gz) tar xzvf "$1" -C "$3"
            ;;
        *.rar) unrar e "$1" "$3"
            ;;
        *.tar) tar xvf "$1" -C "$3"
            ;;
        *.bz2) bunzip2 "$1" -c > "$3"
            ;;
        *.tbz) tar xjvf "$1" -C "$3"
            ;;
        *.gz) gunzip "$1" -c > "$3"
            ;;
        *.tgz) tar xzvf "$1" -C "$3"
            ;;
        *.jar) unzip "$1" -d "$3"
            ;;
        *.xz) tar xvf "$1" -C "$3"
            ;;
        *.zip) unzip "$1" -d "$3"
            ;;
        *.Z) uncompress "$1" -c > "$3"
            ;;
        *) echo "No extraction option for $1" >&2
            exit 1
    esac
else
    error >&2
    exit 1
fi
```
````

Comment: Make sure you use the https://shellcheck.net tool to validate your syntax.

Comment: Taking a second look at this, it's admirable quality for (as you say) as scripting newbie. The only real oops I see is that your help says that multiple  input files are allowed, but this code only handles one.

Comment: I use shellcheck.net constantly, its great. And I see what you mean going to change that. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure why we have `#!/bin/bash` - it looks like plain, portable `#!/bin/sh` would be fine here.

Things I immediately like include the good error handling, using `&2` for error messages and exiting non-zero.

All the `tar` commands can be combined, as `tar` is able (with `-a`) to automatically identify any compression scheme it handles.

As there's no need to continue once the archiver is run, we can replace the shell process using `exec`.  E.g.

```
case $1 in
    *.7z) exec 7z e "$1"
        ;;
```

Don't do that if we extend the program to process multiple input files, though (see below).

If we take the usual convention of flags first, then it makes it easier when we decide we want to handle more options (e.g. `-v`, so we can default to quiet operation).  And we can combine the two big `case` constructs by always passing a directory, but defaulting to the current working directory:

```
destination=.

die() {
    printf '%s\n' "$@" >&2
    exit 1
}

do_extract() {
    case $1 in
        *.tar.*|*.t[bg]z) tar xaf "$1" -C "$destination"
            ;;
        *.jar|*.zip) unzip "$1" -d "$destination"
            ;;
        # ...
    esac
}

while [ $# -ge 1 ]
do
    case "$1" in
        -d)
            [ $# -gt 1 ] || die "Usage: $0 [-d directory] file..."
            destination=$2
            shift 2
            ;;
        -*)
            die "Unrecognised option: $1"
        *)
            do_extract "$1"
            shift
    esac
done
```

Be careful with `echo`:

> ```
> usage() {
>     echo "Usage: nzip [FILE]..."
>     echo "By default file(s) will be extracted to the working directory."
>     echo
>     echo "OPTIONS.."
>     echo
>     echo "-d, --directory, eg. nzip [file] [-d] [directory]"
>     echo
>     echo
> }
> ```

Other (e.g. future) versions of `echo` may treat that `-d` as indicating a flag.

I'd be inclined to use a here-file for this:

```
usage() {
    cat <<'END'
Usage: nzip [FILE] [-d DESTINATION]
By default file(s) will be extracted to the working directory.

OPTIONS:
    -d destination
END
}
```

Note that I've changed the usage line, because we support only one file, and `-d` and the destination argument go together (and it's misleading to call it "directory" when it may be a non-directory name if we're unpacking a single file).

Comment: thanks for all that great information. I implemented most of what you suggested. at least the parts I understood. I still have a lot to learn. i know "-eq" is equal to, does "-ge" mean greater or equal to? and "-gt" is just greater than? also not sure what shift does. and why not just set destination=$2 from the start.

Comment: Yes, you've guessed those operators correctly.  `man test` or `man [` for the full details (though Bash has its own `test` built-in, so `man bash-builtins` is probably what you want; that's also where to find a description of `shift`).

Comment: The `while [ $# -ge 1 ]` (or simply `while [ "$@" ]`) loop with `shift` is a fairly common idiom for reading option arguments in shell scripts; expect to see that fairly frequently when working with shell.

Answer (score 4):

Building on [Toby's excellent answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/254625/3219), this offers 2 alternate ways to parse the options.

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

readonly PROGRAM=${0##*/}

readonly USAGE=$(cat <<END_USAGE
Usage: $PROGRAM [FILE]...

By default file(s) will be extracted to the working directory.

OPTIONS

-d, --directory, eg. nzip [file] [-d directory]

END_USAGE
)

die()   { printf '%s\n' "$*" >&2; exit 1; }
error() { die "For help, type: $PROGRAM -h"; }
usage() { echo "$USAGE"; exit 0; }

extract() {
    local file=$1 dest=$2
    echo "various ways to decompress $file to $dest"
}

# default destination is the current directory
destination="."


############################################################
# parse options
```

Now, we can use the bash builtin `getopts` to parse the options, but it only allows for short options

```bsh
while getopts :hd: opt; do
    case $opt in
        h) usage ;;
        d) destination=$OPTARG ;;
        :) die "Missing option for -$OPTARG" ;;
        *) error ;;
    esac
done
shift $((OPTIND - 1))
```

Or use the external `getopt` tool to allow long options too

```bsh
tmp=$( getopt -o 'hd:' --long 'help,directory:' -n "$PROGRAM" -- "$@" ) || exit $?
eval set -- "$tmp"

while true; do
    case $1 in
        '-h'|'--help') usage ;;
        '-d'|'--directory') 
            destination=$2
            shift 2
            ;;
        '--')
            shift
            break
            ;;
        *)  die 'Internal error' ;;
    esac
done
```

And then:

```bsh
############################################################
# after option parsing

(( $# > 0 )) || usage

for file in "$@"; do
    extract "$file" "$destination"
done
```